EF Core - Configure row version for all entities that derive from a base class
In order to have a row version on an entity the documentation guides to do this:
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<SomeEntity> SomeEntities { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<SomeEntity>()
            .Property(b => b.Version)
            .IsRowVersion();
    }
}

public class SomeEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public uint Version { get; set; }
}

Since many of my entities need this row version, how can I put it in a base class (or interface) and configure EF to automatically add row version for them?
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public uint Version { get; set; }
}

public class SomeEntity1 : BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class SomeEntity2 : BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}


Try conventions.
See Model bulk configuration
public class RowVersionConvention : IModelFinalizingConvention
{
    public void ProcessModelFinalizing(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder,
        IConventionContext<IConventionModelBuilder> context)
    {
        foreach (var property in modelBuilder.Metadata.GetEntityTypes()
                    .SelectMany(entityType =>
                        entityType.GetDeclaredProperties().Where(
                            property => property.ClrType == typeof(uint)
                                     && property.Name == "Version")))
        {
            property.Builder.HasColumnType("rowversion"); // xmin
        }
    }
}

Tested in Sql Server.
In PostgreSQL should be "xmin", I think.
Add convention in DbContext:
protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
{
    configurationBuilder.Conventions.Add(_ => new RowVersionConvention());
}

